# "these days" vs "so far this year"

Tags: grammar

I have to choose between "these days" and "so far this year" in this sentence:

> I am not making much money ***these days/so far this year***.

The problem is that both phrases make sense to me. According to the answers in the book the correct one is "these days".

What am I missing? Why is "so far this year" wrong?

Comment: Syntactically, the second version should be worded, *I have not made much money so far this year.*

Comment: Welcome! One important point: books, tests, quizzes, etc. often give only one of several possible right answers. Texasboy shows one explanation of why your answer could be "wrong," but it's certainly not outside of regular conversational usage. Your book is not the only authority!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use **so far this year** you would have to rephrase the sentence a bit, since **so far** refers to *the past*, and not something you're currently doing.

Change **I am not making** to **I have not made**, and it would be correct to use the second option.

> I have not made much money so far this year.

However when changing to past tense, you can ***not*** use **these days** anymore, since **these days** refer to something right now.

> I am not making much money these days

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for contributing! I have to say I disagree a bit, though, since "I'm making [amount of money]" can also be used to talk about salary rate. It would be appropriate to say "I'm making more money this year than I was last year." Adding "so far" could still be reasonable (if perhaps not strictly grammatical) if the person was expecting change in their salary.